# How to check if integer array is spiral sorted?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, list, sorting

Spiral Sort Involves: a[0] <= a[n-1] <= a[1] <= a[n-2] <= a[2]....
How would i check if a given array is spiral sorted or not?

I have tried this the brute force way.

Comment: Can you explain what the brute force way is and why you think a better way exists?

Comment: @user7 There might be a better way than bruteforce

Comment: I can't comment on that without knowing what your brute force way is

Comment: Only caveat is you need to stop when you reach the middle of the array. After *n* - 1 comparisons, that is.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your "brute force" way is to iterate the array in the "spiral" sequence and check that each element is greater or equal to the previous one.  For an array of size `N`, this requires `N - 1` comparisons.

Modulo details of how you actually code that algorithm, there is no better way to check that an array is spiral sorted.  The "brute force" algorithm does the minimum number of comparisons required by theory.